# Typo on search pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

All of the [search options pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search) on the network - okay, I haven't checked them all, but I've checked five or six, and it seems like they're all copied and pasted from some original somewhere - have an extra slash in the example URL at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: I've looked at that page tons of times and never noticed that, huh. Good catch!

Comment: If it works like the privileges "wiki" pages then the source is [here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search)

Comment: It'd be rather surprising if you had found a site where that's *not* the case, since there's no copy&paste -- it's all the same file :)

Comment: @balpha I figured. Didn't want to make assumptions, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woops, fixed in the next build.